# Tableview cell in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

`dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` is expecting string as a parameter. But, when I am passing string then it is showing error.

**Code:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

if cell == nil {
cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
}

    //we know that cell is not empty now so we use ! to force unwrapping

cell!.textLabel.text = "abc"
cell!.detailTextLabel.text = "1/2"


return cell }
```

**Problem**:

Downcast from UITableViewCell? to UITableViewCell only unwraps options.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is declared as `UITableViewCell?` so just delete the type casting.

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL")
```

It's always helpful to use Quick Help or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click on the symbol to lookup the declaration.